# Smooth cylinder after do kife cut?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, edges, faces

[image: Knife & Smooth]

As the image shown I did a cut inside a cylinder, then I want to smooth cylinder but keep the cut sharp. When I did smooth the shape distort around the circular hole :(

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/how-to-cut-a-rounded-hole-in-a-sphere

Comment: this link will give you some ideas on how to deal with this kind of cuts: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA

Comment: If you haven't solved this yet this is pretty good quick tut.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=salpctjEdAA

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you did a Boolean cut. That gets the job done fast, but you'll have a hard time cleaning up the mesh after the fact. You would be better off by first cutting a hole in the cylinder with the Knife Tool, taking care that the topology is correct (quads only). Then select, inset and push the polygons that form the perimeter of the hole inside the cylinder. After that, select the edges surrounding the newly formed hole and bevel them. After you apply the Subdivision Surface Modifier you should have a decent looking mesh.

Comment: While correct, cutting a hole with Knife Project will actually leave nearly the same topology requiring cleaning up as cutting with Boolean.

Comment: Agreed. Maybe a better option would be more planning with the overall shape and poly-count, i.e. Boolean cut with a low-poly cylinder primitive and eventually adding edges with the Knife tool where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the geometry of your model is not super important and you just want it to look the part you can set the shading to smooth on the object under the first tab on the t tray of the 3D view.[image]

Then if you go to the data tab under normals there is an autosmooth option that will tell blender not to smooth edges that exceed the angle you set.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Non of those methods work perfectly, still some distortion after do mesh :(