# Extrude/scale on cylinder

Tags: extrude, scale

I'm trying to make a window in a tower but the tower is made with a cylinder (32 vertices), set smooth from the left panel (Tools > Transform) and select auto-smoth (30d°) in data panel.
The create a window using another object and a boolean difference operation.
when I extrude and scale to add detail on window the result is not clean (see screenshot 2 -> square things in the mesh).
Does anyone already handle this problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: what you're trying to do is not clear, you could please show your mesh in wireframe mode, or share your file?

Comment: Just a wild guess but you might want to try smoothing the object with the tools panel. Other than that as via comment you'd need to provide more information on what you are doing.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3260/599

Comment: Likely the curvature of the cut for the window doesn't correlate with the curvature of the cylinder itself so you see shading artifact even though no Ngons are used. Try going with topology like https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRO6g.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Made without Booleans, this sort of topology stands up to pretty close scrutiny, (if you don't mind the holding loops around the tower).

The extra vertical loops in the cylinder that help define the curvature of the arch were created by selecting the relevant edge-rings, and using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Subdivide *Smooth*.

The arch can be formed  by selecting its central vertice(s) and in Proportional Edit, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, raising it/them in Z.

Then an inset and extrusions to create the holding perimeter and the thickness of the window, and an extra edge loop to hold the sharpness of its bottom corners.

[image]