# Deformation when making a circular hole in a helmet

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make a hole in a helmet. Can somebody tell me why this happened?

[image]

Comment: I guess bad geometry, and subsurf. Search here many other similar issues with holes and weird results

Comment: are you using solidify modifier?

Comment: Could you describe what you did here? The problem is the geometry. Using ngons (polygons with more than 4 vertices) and applying modifiers to it, will cause crazy deformations and artifacts like the one you have. When using boolean operations, you will often need to go in and fix things to make it work properly. This means either adding more geometry to your main mesh or using a cyclinder with less vertices and you'll also need to merge vertices together make sure your faces are 4 vertices or less if you want to use other modifiers on top. Could you provide more information in your question?

Comment: Watch this video: [8 ways of cutting holes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA).  Read also these related links: [Cutting a hole in a cylinder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856) and [Cutting a rounded hole in a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/how-to-cut-a-rounded-hole-in-a-sphere)