# How to round a square face?

Tags: faces

[image: a screenshot of my Blender file]

Im trying to make eyes for a stick figure model in Blender, so I need to convert some faces from square to round. How do I do that?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/how-to-cut-a-rounded-hole-in-a-sphere